# Terraform keeps destroying internet gateway forever

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a set of `.tf` files that reflect an `AWS` infra.

The files in my `terraform` folder are more or less:

```
eip.tf
instance.tf
key.tf
provider.tf
rds.tf
route53.tf
securitygroup.tf
terraform.tfstate
terraform.tfstate.1520442018.backup
terraform.tfstate.backup
terraform.tfvars
terraform.tfvars.dist
vars.tf
vpc.tf
```

I created the infra and I want to destroy it.

I see that the internet gateway destruction takes forever:

```
aws_internet_gateway.my-gw: Still destroying... (ID: igw-d53fa0b2, 14m50s elapsed)
```

By browsing in my `aws` console I see that this is because my `ec2` instance is still up and running.

Why is terraform trying to destroy the internet gateway without making sure the ec2 instance is down?

How can I prevent this from hapenning again?

The same scripts have executed (`apply`/`destroy`) many times before without any issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this was due to my instance having been created with this:

```
  # enable termination protection
  disable_api_termination = true
```

This will apparently prevent normal termination behavior from terraform.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue but mine was because I had deletion protection turned on for a Load Balancer

```
enable_deletion_protection = true
```

I just logged into AWS and manually disabled by editing the Load Balancer.

[image: Edit load balancer attributes dialog]

I suppose you could `terraform apply` the change and then `terraform destroy` everything but if you're seeing this error you've most likely destroyed most of your infrastructure already and you don't want to re-create it all just to allow you to destroy it all again.